# If my DNS is a VM with HA do I need a secondary?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtual-machines, high-availability

Same question would apply to mail server - if I have these running as VMs with failover / HA do I need to run a secondary / backup for either?

This is a relatively small site (< 50 machines) so load balancing isn't a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Need` is ultimately only ever going to be relative.

However - you need to be aware that failover / HA will only protect against host failures - not Operating System / Application level failures. It's key that you take into account the different failure modes and the different ways to protect.

For example, HA will also require shared storage - this in itself could become a single point of failure for your server.

You need to weigh up the likelyhood of such failures along with how detrimental downtime will be.

Comment: Good points. I would likely make the 'mistake' of keeping primary/secondary on the same OS / patch schedule so any software failures would effect everyone.

Comment: ad patching: In larger environments it is worthy to have some separate testing machines. First patch them, then wait at least few days if anything bad shows up. If it doesn't, it is relatively safe to patch production servers.

Answer (score 6):

DNS is a fundamental service for your clients and servers to carry out their functions. In the event a host fails, you are stuck waiting the 60 to 300 seconds for HA to recover that VM, assuming it comes up safe. If your clients are patient people who can wait for this recovery? You might be okay.

I would have two DNS servers before bothering with say two DHCP servers or two mailbox hosts. If you're running Active Directory to manage this network then two domain controllers, each running on a separate virtual host is a MUST.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you're protecting against. Let's assume this is VMware and you're referring to the [HA capabilities](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features-high-availability) of VMware vSphere.

- HA will help reduce the downtime incurred by a failure of an ESXi host.
- HA will not protect you against local site/facility related issues or network connectivity problems.
- HA won't help if there are storage issues.

However, DNS and mail (specifically, SMTP) have redundancy built into the protocols. It's not difficult to make DNS resilient through the use of multiple resolvers/DCs. Inbound SMTP can be bolstered by the use of multiple MX records or a backup MX service.

What's *your* biggest concern?